# C While loop does not exit correctly

Tags: c

I have to take a university course on C and I shall read in some integers with a while loop. The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max 100

int main(){
  int a[max];
  int i,n;

  printf("Enter the number of persons: ");
  do{
    scanf("%i", &n);
  }while((n < 1) || (n > max));

  i = 0;
  while (i < n){
    printf("Enter the age of the %i th Person", i+1);
    scanf("%i", &a[i]);
    i = i + 1;
  }
 /* further code */
```

It compiles (with the gcc compiler), but as soon as I get into the loop, it reads in the numbers correctly, but after the last input, nothing is executed anymore.

Comment: Not the immediate issue but you're being naughty and not checking the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: Address of n in scanf

Comment: @HayriUğurKoltuk, nice spot, answers in the answers section please?

Comment: *"It compiles (with the gcc compiler)"* `printf("Enter the age of the %i th Person, i+1);` I doubt that.

Comment: `i` is not initialised before you use it in the second loop.

Comment: Sorry, the adress of n is in the example. I just forgot it.

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and compile your code with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Also, end your `printf` format string with `\n`

Comment: Read also carefully the documentation of *every* function you are using, including of [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and of [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: Your code as it stands here __now__ is fine (except for not checking the return value of `scanf` which is not the issue right here). But anyway you should put the `printf("Enter the number of persons: ");`  into the loop, otherwise the user won't understand what's going on if he types a value > 100 or < 1. What __excatly__  is the problem now?

Answer (score 3):

Initialise `i`

```
int i = 0;
int n;
```

[edit: I see now that you have edited your code as I suggested]

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `i = 0`

Here is the working code.

```
#define max 5 
int main()
{
    int a[max];
    int i = 0,n;

    printf("Enter the number of persons:\n");
    do{
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }while((n < 1) || (n > max));

    while (i < n){
        printf("Enter the age of the %i th Person:\n", i+1);
        scanf("%i", &a[i]);
        i = i + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And how exactly is the OP going to learn what he is doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

i has a garbage value at first you should write

```
i=0
```

at first
and than

```
 scanf("%d", &n);
```

Because you are calling a while loop with a garbage value of i at the beginning and code executes if the belove statistics satisfied

```
 while((n < 1) || (n > max))
```

but i has no value so you do not increment it. Think about sum,count I'm sure you know what i mean. if you want to increment something you should define first. An integer i defined with no value cant increment. Use for loop at last loop, instead of while